# Link open from Browser Download History Pass by my Validation Route in Flask

Tags: python-2.7, flask

By Previously, my user have successfully downloaded a file in my Flask Application when I had not set any restriction or validation in the downloaded route. However, later I set some validation, simply to `return '' 404`, so that user was not able to download a file. It is for testing purpose before I could proceed further.

However, the problem is when my user open link from his download history in their browser, in this case Chrome, the file was downloaded successfully again passing by my validation `404` response.

```
from werkzeug import secure_filename

@app.route('/packages/download/<filename>', methods=['GET'])
def DownloadPackages(filename):

    return '', 404 # User should not have downloaded file. But why he still be able to download from history in browser


    ConfigPath  = 'PYTHON_PACKAGE'

    Path        = os.path.abspath(app.config.get(ConfigPath))
    Path        = os.path.join(Path,filename)


    return send_from_directory(Path, filename=secure_filename(filename))
```

Could anyone explain why this happen? How can I do the validation on this? I am testing on my local machine.

### Added:

- I have noticed that the link opened from previous download history does not show up in the terminal console running flask application.
- Also even I stopped flask from running in terminal console, the file was still able to be downloaded from Link Download History.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, since there is no one comment or answer to my question and I have the solution myself.

The issue was caused by cache data on the browser when we downloaded the file. And the solution is to disable cache data on browser with several ways. The best ways I chose to implement is done through server side with the help of Flask like this.

```
#  disable cache when download file
response = send_from_directory(Path, filename=secure_filename(filename), as_attachment=True)
response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
response.headers["Expires"] = "0"
response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=0'

return response
```

With this, there will be no cache when the file was downloaded, and again the sequence download will be started from fresh which will be checked and validated as my code snippet in my question.

Hope this is helpful to other developer seeking the solution to the as mine.

Thanks,

Regards